# get all the contact name from Account Query

Tags: soql

list acc=[select id,name,(select name from contacts) from Account];
 For(Account Act:acc){
List con=Act.contacts;
system.debug('The Contact Name Is'+ con.name );
}

I want to debug all the contact name without using for loop to parse the contacts data from the "acc".

I am new at salesforce and don't know how to do this so plzz help. Plzz Ignore If any Mistakes u notice above

Comment: You have included the correct subquery. What's not working here?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child records are a collection.

```
for (Account record : [/*query*/])
{
    List<Contact> children = record.Contacts;
    for (Contact child : children)
    {
        system.debug(child);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not ask follow up questions in the comments.